# Exposing static methods through proxy classes

Tags: java, ant

We have a Shared Utilities project, two independent SDK projects (each referring to the Utilities) and some plugin projects, each using only one of those SDKs. Shared Utilities contains some all-static classes, which need to be made visible to the plugins mentioned, but we'd like to hide the rest of its classes from them.

How we can go about resolving the issue? We'd like to keep the build process as simple as possible (we're using Ant for the build) with least possible dependencies.

Here's the options we've considered so far and why we've discarded each approach:

1. Second Shared Utilities project, which will be made available to the plugins - will make deployment harder.
2. Build 2 separate .jar-s from the Shared Utils project, one containing only the all-static utilities and the other - whatever needs to be hidden. This would make the build more complex, i.e. additional dependencies to the plugins' build scripts.
3. Proxy all-static classes in each of the SDKs - duplicate method definitions, but the implementation simply calls the corresponding static method from the Shared project - seems most painless, downside is we'd need to copy the Javadoc by hand. Is there a simple Javadoc tag, which would do this automatically upon generation?
4. Convert all-static classes to "normal" and simply create subclasses in each SDK - unnecessary (to my mind) performance overhead.

Comment: what preformance overhead do you mean?

Comment: We'd need to create a new object almost every time we need to use one of those methods - yes, object creation is rather cheap, because the object wouldn't have any properties, but it's still there. Also, it would make the code "uglier" and harder to read. I can already picture people scratching their heads on code like this. :)

Comment: If these are utility classes what sort of methods are you trying to hide? Sounds like you need separate "Utilities" projects to me. Import both into your SDK projects and only the one with the more public methods into the Plugins.

Comment: @JohnMark13 Some singleton and static classes, which are shared between other projects, dependent on this Shared Utils. A new project would certainly be a correct solution, but I'd like to avoid the extra complexity, associated with introducing it (build and deployment). One idea was creating the new project for in-IDE-use only and on build creating a single .jar from it and the existing SharedUtils for deployment purposes, but it would make it harder to follow the dependencies logic.

Comment: You can have 2 ant build files for same project. You can specify source directories for each build. Exclude directories for each build which you don't want to go in output jar. This way you can generate 2 jars for same project with selected classes.

Comment: There may be some complexity now, but long term the separation will be more manageable than using ANT to select which classes should be built out. If you do go the ANT route, you do note need two files, just have two build targets.

Comment: @Pranalee I was thinking more like having a single build file and using <exclude> tags, but this did cross my mind. The problem is the plugins would still need additional classpath configuration. Coming to think of it, one other option is to include the required classes in the SDK's jar - downside is when it is deployed, I will end up with these classes getting loaded multiple times, thought this shouldn't be a problem, since methods don't reference static fields.

Comment: @JohnMark13 Agreed about manageability, I would really like to find a way to avoid introducing a new project, but I am leaning towards this solution if I don't find a way.

Comment: For question 3: use the see-tag. Your proxies should be generated, but I'd prefer the extra project. Sounds more "correct".

Answer (score 0):

"Exposing static methods through proxy classes"
I've read your complete question and I'm not sure what is your issue exactly.
Exposing static (non-instance related) method through a proxy (instance).

What you wan't to hide from what exactly. What you want to expose to what exactly.

```
public class A {

private A(){} //prevent instanciation

public static void doSomething(){} //want to expose to some class, hide from other

}
```

To limit exposition of doSomething you can set the visibility: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

You can also remove the static nature and use a static factory pattern to return the object like:

```
public class A {

private A(){} 

public void doSomething(){} //want to expose to some class, hide from other

//the new A can also be set in a member variable and 
//return always the same instance, if it is unmuttable it will be thread safe.
public static A getInstance(){ return new A();}

}
```

This can look like the "same thing" but you can now control the visibility of all method in A by controlling only the visibility of the getInstance(), the javadoc stay on A, now to control exactly how the getInstance can be access... I would have to understand exactly what you want to do.